# Notifee foreground notification not working properly

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am setting up @notifee/react-native with @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/messaging to display notification.I am recieving notifications properly in all 3 cases, foreground, background and killed.
In my index.js I have these set and working :

```
notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
   // do screen redirection by using the custom data from the payload
)
messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(onMessageReceived);
```

onMessageReceived is the function where the data is handled and notifee is used to display the notification.

```
notifee.displayNotification({
   id: notification.messageId,
   title: title,
   body: messageBody,
   data: notification.data,
   android: {
     channelId: 'default',
     pressAction: {
       id: 'default',
     },
   }
})
```

`notifee.getInitialNotification()` is also working and is sending the payload that I use to perform redirection.

My issue is with foreground notifications.

**How I expect it'd work**
App is on the screen, a notification comes and on press it does some action ( screen redirection in my case )

**How it actually works**

1. If the app was opened from the app tray, then a notification comes on the foreground, the app just restarts and the redirection does not work. In this case, if another notification comes in foreground, then the redirection works but only after app restart.
2. If the app was opened from notification, the foreground notification works fine but again, only after restart.